# CSCore with audio through a GoXLR

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, audio, cscore

I'm building an audio visualizer app in Unity and I'm currently using WASAPI to get the audio from any app playing audio.

I recently had someone with a GoXLR test it and the visualizer wasn't picking up the audio. I think all the audio is going directly to the GoXLR bypassing WASAPI. I can't debug it myself as I don't have a GoXLR so I wanted to know how I could pick up the audio from the GoXLR.

Comment: Can you add an AudioSouce component one by one?

Comment: Can unity's own "OnAudioFilterRead(float[] data, int channels)" method try to get audio?

Comment: I'm not even using AudioSource component I'm reading the spectrum data straight from WASAPI. It's not actually playing the audio in the Unity engine, it just takes the audio from any app in the background and passes the spectrum values to the engine and that's what I'm working with.